# Height of a frame in pixels

Tags: html, css, border, frames

I have 70 pixel high image. I want to create a frame precisely in such a way that I can tile its background with this image without causing a scrollbar to appear.

Intended result:

```
-------
|this has 70 pixels
--------
| the rest
```

my html looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<frameset rows="70,*">
    <frame noresize src="a.htm" >
    <frame noresize src="b.htm" >
</frameset>
</html>
```

a.htm looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"
<html><head><title></title></head>
<body style="background-image:url(70px_img.gif);background-repeat:repeat;" >
    <img src="another_70_px_img.png" style="float:left;" />
</body>
</html>
```

Right now, the inside of the first freame apparently gets more than 70 pixels, making a scrollbar appear. It also messes up the other image inside, since it gets a tiny empty space and the bottom is cropped. Is it possible to make the inner frame in such a way that is has the precise height - I'm wondering if there is some border I have to set somewhere.

I know about `scrolling="no"`.  But this doesn't stop the inner picture looking out of whack. I can "solve" the croping problem by giving the inner picture `height:50px` but not `height:XX%` but this doesn't seem right.

I also know frames are evil, and plan to repurpose this into a `<div>` later. Will transition be smooth or will I have to realign things all over again?

Comment: just throw out the frames now and set it up the proper way :)

Comment: Agreed. I've never found a use for them either. What are you trying to lay out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the margins and padding of html and body inside the frames:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body { margin:0; padding: 0}
</style>
```

This may get you started, but depending on what you want more may be needed. `scrolling=no` is probably also needed.

Yes, frames are deprecated. Odds are you shouldn't be using them - but only you can know!

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow:hidden;` to prevent the scrollbars if you don't have content going over the edges.

```
<body style="background-image:url(70px_img.gif);background-repeat:repeat;overflow:hidden;" >
```